# ReactJS promise won't fulfill

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, es6-promise

I am working in React trying to automate my homepage (using a component to render bootstrap layout components) and render the pics from an assets file. The promise returns a module which has access to the fileLocation of which I need to be the final return. However, every time I try to access it(**.then(val => val.default[0])**, it send another promise to be resolved. I tried to add more **.then** however it keeps giving me the same promise over and over again.

Here is the code :

```
function ReviewSection(props){

  function renderPics(numRow, numCol) {
    var render =  [];
    var children = [];

    async function getPics(index){
      var location = await import("./assets/img/index")
      .then(val => val.default[index])
      .then(data => data)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

      return location
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
      for (let x = 0; x < numCol; x++) { 
        if(x % 2 === 0){
          console.log(getPics(x).then(val => val.default[0]))
          children.push(<Col><Image src={getPics(x)}/></Col>)
        }
        else{
          children.push(<Col><div style={{width: "4rem"}}></div></Col>)
        }
      }
      render.push(<Row>{children.map(val => val)}</Row>)
      children = [];
    }
    return render.map(val => val)
  }

  return (
    <Container >
      <Row>
        <Col>
          {renderPics(props.rows, props.cols)}
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

The file **./assets/img/index** looks like this :

```
// images.js



var trustedPartners = {
  0: require('./trustedPartners/remax-logo-og.jpg'),
  1: require('./trustedPartners/coldwell.jpeg'),
  2: require('./trustedPartners/bluediamond.jpg'),
  3: require('./trustedPartners/exp.png'),
  4: require('./trustedPartners/greglynn.png'),
  5: require('./trustedPartners/kingsway.png'),
  6: require('./trustedPartners/liveurban.jpg'),
  7: require('./trustedPartners/maison.jpg'),
  8: require('./trustedPartners/prb.png'),
  9: require('./trustedPartners/rebroker.jpg'),
  10: require('./trustedPartners/woods.jpg'),
  11: require('./trustedPartners/paigefulton.jpg'),
  12: require('./trustedPartners/atlas.png'),
  13: require('./trustedPartners/meinhaus.png')
}


export default trustedPartners
```

Here is Chrome console:
[image: Like I said I tried adding another .then to it, still no use.]

Comment: Look into `useState` and `useEffect`. Those hooks are key components to deal with asynchronous behavior like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper way to use promise. You have to use a callback to return the fetch value from API. Another way is that you return the API response, not the whole API.

```
function ReviewSection(props) {

function renderPics(numRow, numCol) {
    var render = [];
    var children = [];

    async function getPics(index) {
        var location = await import("./assets/img/index")
            .then(val => {
                return val.default[index];
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                return '';
            });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < numCol; x++) {
            if (x % 2 === 0) {
                console.log(getPics(x))
                children.push(<Col><Image src={getPics(x)}/></Col>)
            } else {
                children.push(<Col>
                    <div style={{width: "4rem"}}></div>
                </Col>)
            }
        }
        render.push(<Row>{children.map(val => val)}</Row>)
        children = [];
    }
    return render.map(val => val)
}

return (
    <Container>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                {renderPics(props.rows, props.cols)}
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
)
```

}

It should work for you.